# vb.net combobox.valuemember query?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

Hi I have the following code which will pull information from a database table

```
Private Sub frm_8_IncidentResponseSelect_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txt_incidentid.Text = frm_6_UpdateIncident.txt_incidentid.Text

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim query As String = "select [response id] as responseid, " & _
        " ([response ID] &' '&[response date]) As responsedetails " & _
        " from response where [incident id] = " & txt_incidentid.Text & " "
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Non Conformance\NonConformance.accdb")
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                connection.Open()
                adapter.Fill(dt)
                connection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        cb_responseid.DataSource = dt
        cb_responseid.DisplayMember = "responsedetails"
        cb_responseid.ValueMember = "responseid"
    End If
end sub
```

Based on this code when looking in the combobox I can see the following options displayed

14 02/02/15

15 03/02/15

Which is as intended, I have then added in the following code to test what valuemember is being returned after highlighting one of the combobox box options

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    MsgBox(cb_responseid.ValueMember)
end sub
```

Based on this code I would expect the message box to either return a value of  14  or  15  but all it displays is 'responseid'

What causes this? how do I get it to display as intended or is that not possible?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ValueMember property is the name of the column of your datasource used to keep the Value of the Items in your combobox.

If you want to get the Value of that item you should use the [SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property

You should take care that this property is not null and you should convert its value to the proper datatype (Of course this is required if you run your project with Option Strict On as best practice)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim curValue As Integer
    if cb_responseid.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing then
        curValue = DirectCast(cb_responseid.SelectedValue, Integer)
        MsgBox(curValue)
    End if
end sub
```